# exact phrase match query in solr

Tags: solr, exact-match

I want to do an exact match query with Solr. I have already a solr.textField type to make fuzzy and stemmed searches, but I need to be able to do exact match (or "contains" match) queries, like this

```
document_1.text_exact: "The fox was jumping on the goose"
document_2.text_exact: "The fox is jumping on the goose"
document_3.text_exact: "The fox is jumping at the goose"
```

I want to do a query like this:

```
 text_exact:"The fox is jumping"
```

and I want solr document_2 and document_3 but not document_1. The same you can do when looking for text in Firefox (you know, with Ctrl-F).

How shoud I define the "text_exact" field in order to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: In the end I just had a problem with multi-word queries, I just had to surround the query with parentheses. Thanks anyway nikhil500.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define a field without stop-words filter.
2. If you don't want `"The fox is jump"` to match, then remove stemming filter from the field.
3. If you don't want `"the fox is jumping"` to match, then remove the lower case filter from the field.